# Find Variability Monthly Data by Year of Long-Term Monthly Average

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns, deviation

I need to find the variability from the long-term mean for monthly data from 1991 to 2021. I have data that looks like this that is a 204,3 size:

```
dfavgs = 
     plant_name  month     power_kwh
0     ARIZONA I      1  10655.989885
1     ARIZONA I      2   9789.542672
2     ARIZONA I      3   7889.403154
3     ARIZONA I      4   7965.595843
4     ARIZONA I      5   9299.316756
..          ...    ...           ...
199  SANTANA II      8  16753.999870
200  SANTANA II      9  17767.383616
201  SANTANA II     10  17430.005363
202  SANTANA II     11  16628.784139
203  SANTANA II     12  15167.085560
```

My large monthly by year df looks like this with size 6137,4:

```
dfmonthlys:
      plant_name  year  month     power_kwh
0      ARIZONA I  1991      1   9256.304704
1      ARIZONA I  1991      2   8851.689732
2      ARIZONA I  1991      3   7649.949328
3      ARIZONA I  1991      4   6728.544028
4      ARIZONA I  1991      5   8601.165457
     ...   ...    ...           ...
6132  SANTANA II  2020      9  16481.202361
6133  SANTANA II  2020     10  15644.358737
6134  SANTANA II  2020     11  14368.804306
6135  SANTANA II  2020     12  15473.958468
6136  SANTANA II  2021      1  13161.219086
```

My new df "dfvar" should look like this showing the monthly deviation from long-term mean by year - i don't think these values are correct below:

```
  plant_name  year  month       Var
0  ARIZONA I  1991      1 -0.250259
1  ARIZONA I  1991      2 -0.283032
2  ARIZONA I  1991      3 -0.380370
3  ARIZONA I  1991      4 -0.455002
4  ARIZONA I  1991      5 -0.303324
```

I could do this easily in MATLAB but i'm not sure how to do this using pandas which i need to learn. Thank you very much. I've tried this below which gives me a series but there seem to be unexpected NaN's at the end rows:

```
t = dfmonthlys['power_kwh']/dfavgs.loc[:,'power_kwh'] - 1
```

the output from above looks like this:

```
t
Out[159]: 
0      -0.131352
1      -0.095802
2      -0.030351
3      -0.155299
4      -0.075076

6132         NaN
6133         NaN
6134         NaN
6135         NaN
6136         NaN
Name: power_kwh, Length: 6137, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example code of how you could do it. `merge` the dfavgs to the monthly data by month and plant name and then `assign` the calculation to a new column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dfavgs = {'plant_name':np.append(np.repeat(["ARIZONA I"], 12) , np.repeat("SANTANA II", 12)),
          'month': np.tile(range(1, 13), 2),
          'mnth_power_kwh': np.concatenate(([10655, 9789, 7889, 7965, 9299],
                                      range(8000, 1500, -1000), range(12000, 500, -1000)))}

dfavgs=pd.DataFrame(dfavgs)

dfmonthlys = {'plant_name':np.append(np.repeat("ARIZONA I", 24), np.repeat("SANTANA II", 24)),
          'year': np.tile(np.repeat([1991, 1992], 12), 2),
        'month': np.tile(np.tile(range(1, 13), 2), 2),
          'power_kwh': np.concatenate(([9256, 8851, 7649, 6728, 8601],
                                 range(7000, 500, -1000),
                                 range(13000, 1500, -1000),
                                       range(25000, 1500, -1000)))}

dfmonthlys=pd.DataFrame(dfmonthlys)

merg=pd.merge(dfmonthlys, dfavgs, how="left", on=["month", "plant_name"])\
       .assign(diff = lambda x: x["power_kwh"]/x["mnth_power_kwh"]-1)

print merg
```